# What is the difference between Magisterial teaching and Sacred Tradition in Roman Catholicism?

Tags: catholicism

In an answer to another question, @PeterTurner wrote:

> Good answers from a Catholic perspective should be able to stand on all three legs of Sacred Scripture, Magisterial teaching and Sacred Tradition

What is the difference between the last two items, and can an example of each be given?

Comment: I wasn't sure if it were good or bad form to call out the name of someone I'm quoting.

Comment: It's very much proper form to cite quotations. You might even link to the post. It's only really an issue if you do so in a negative manner.

Answer (score 7):

As Peter pointed out the Church's authority rests upon Sacred Scripture, Sacred Tradition, and Magisterial teaching/interpretation.

Apostolic Tradtion is the root source of Christian revelation. Christ entrusted the message of salvation and doctrinal authority to the Apostles, who in turn handed Christ's revelation through apostolic succession (a.k.a. Sacred Tradition).

The CCC defines Tradition:

> THE APOSTOLIC TRADITION
>
> 75 "Christ the Lord, in whom the entire
> Revelation of themost high God is summed
> up, commanded the apostles to preach the
> Gospel, which had been promised
> beforehand by the prophets, and which he
> fulfilled in his own person and promulgated
> with his own lips. In preaching the Gospel,
> they were to communicate the gifts of God
> to all men. This Gospel was to be the source
> of all saving truth and moral discipline."
>
> In the apostolic preaching. . .
>
> 76 In keeping with the Lord's command, the
> Gospel was handed on in two ways:
>
> orally "by the apostles who handed on, by
> the spoken word of their preaching, by the
> example they gave, by the institutions they
> established, what they themselves had
> received - whether from the lips of Christ,
> from his way of life and his works, or
> whether they had learned it at the
> prompting of the Holy Spirit";
>
> in writing "by those apostles and other men
> associated with the apostles who, under the
> inspiration of the same Holy Spirit,
> committed the message of salvation to
> writing".
>
> . . . continued in apostolic succession
>
> 77 "In order that the full and living Gospel
> might always be preserved in the Church the
> apostles left bishops as their successors.
> They gave them their own position of
> teaching authority." Indeed, "the
> apostolic preaching, which is expressed in a
> special way in the inspired books, was to be
> preserved in a continuous line of succession
> until the end of time."
>
> 78 This living transmission, accomplished in
> the Holy Spirit, is called Tradition, since it is
> distinct from Sacred Scripture, though
> closely connected to it. Through Tradition,
> "the Church, in her doctrine, life and
> worship, perpetuates and transmits to every
> generation all that she herself is, all that she
> believes." "The sayings of the holy
> Fathers are a witness to the life-giving
> presence of this Tradition, showing how its
> riches are poured out in the practice and life
> of the Church, in her belief and her prayer."
>
> 79 The Father's self-communication made
> through his Word in the Holy Spirit, remains
> present and active in the Church: "God, who
> spoke in the past, continues to converse
> with the Spouse of his beloved Son. And the
> Holy Spirit, through whom the living voice of
> the Gospel rings out in the Church -and
> through her in the world - leads believers to
> the full truth, and makes the Word of Christ
> dwell in them in all its richness."  (*CCC, Sect. 1, Chapt. 2, Para. 75-79*)

The word Magisterium is just a fancy word for "teaching office." Magisterial teaching is guided by the Holy Spirit to accurately interpret both Tradition and Scripture. The Magisterium is necessary for Sacred Scripture to remain authoritative. Without an authoritative interpreter to interpret Scripture, then Scripture loses its authority. Any one could interpret it anyway they wish. Perhaps this is why there are thousands of denominations.  This is analogous to the necessity of the U. S. Judicial branch  interpreting the Constitution in order to prevent *total* anarchy that would result from the private interpretation of U. S. citizens. However, unlike the Judicial branch, the Magisterium is guided by the Holy Spirit.

The CCC also emphasizes the necessity of an authoritative interpreter to defend and protect the authority of Sacred Tradition and Sacred Scripture:

> THE INTERPRETATION OF THE HERITAGE OF FAITH
>
> The heritage of faith entrusted to the whole of the Church
>
> 84 The apostles entrusted the "Sacred deposit" of the faith (the
> depositum fidei),contained in Sacred Scripture and Tradition, to the
> whole of the Church. "By adhering to [this heritage] the entire holy
> people, united to its pastors, remains always faithful to the teaching
> of the apostles, to the brotherhood, to the breaking of bread and the
> prayers. So, in maintaining, practicing and professing the faith that
> has been handed on, there should be a remarkable harmony between the
> bishops and the faithful."
>
> The Magisterium of the Church
>
> 85 "The task of giving an authentic
> interpretation of the Word of God, whether
> in its written form or in the form of
> Tradition, has been entrusted to the living
> teaching office of the Church alone. Its
> authority in this matter is exercised in the
> name of Jesus Christ." Thismeans that the
> task of interpretation has been entrusted to
> the bishops in communion with the
> successor of Peter, the Bishop of Rome.
>
> 86 "Yet this Magisterium is not superior to
> the Word of God, but is its servant. It
> teaches only what has been handed on to it.
> At the divine command and with the help of
> the Holy Spirit, it listens to this devotedly,
> guards it with dedication and expounds it
> faithfully. All that it proposes for belief as
> being divinely revealed is drawn from this
> single deposit of faith."
>
> 87 Mindful of Christ's words to his apostles:
> "He who hears you, hears me", the
> faithful receive with docility the teachings
> and directives that their pastors give them
> in different forms.
>
> The dogmas of the faith
>
> 88 The Church's Magisterium exercises the
> authority it holds from Christ to the fullest
> extent when it defines dogmas, that is, when
> it proposes, in a form obliging the Christian
> people to an irrevocable adherence of faith,
> truths contained in divine Revelation or also
> when it proposes, in a definitive way, truths
> having a necessary connection with these.
>
> 89 There is an organic connection between
> our spiritual life and the dogmas. Dogmas
> are lights along the path of faith; they
> illuminate it and make it secure. Conversely,
> if our life is upright, our intellect and heart
> will be open to welcome the light shed by
> the dogmas of faith.
>
> 90 The mutual connections between dogmas,
> and their coherence, can be found in the
> whole of the Revelation of the mystery of
> Christ. "In Catholic doctrine there exists
> an order or hierarchy of truths, since they
> vary in their relation to the foundation of
> the Christian faith." (*CCC, Sect. 1, Chapt. 2, Para. 84-90*)

Tradition is the source of both Scripture and the Magisterium. The New Testament wasn't completed until the end of the 1rst cent., and wasn't canonized until the end of the 4rth. The Gospel was transmitted by Tradition and was interpreted by the Magisterium long before the canon was approved by Pope Damasus I. From then on the Church has been supported by those 3 legs.

Comment: This is certainly an authoritative and well-cited answer, but there is so much rote pasting it's hard to get to the answer.

Comment: Hmm...that's odd...I'm usually told I'm guilty of rote prayer :)